# How to test ZF-skeleton app using PHP Storm

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, phpunit, phpstorm

I followed this tutorial http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/unit-testing.html. I checked whether the DbTable\CredentialTreatmentAdapterTest is present and I found it in the location it should exist. However I get a weird error on running the tests. I would like to know how to get a test result as Successful to finish my tutorial. Proceeding which I can focus on understanding the next part in the series. Just need a nudge in this regard.

> X:\ampp\php\php.exe -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php --bootstrap X:\ampp\htdocs\zf2\module\Application\test\Bootstrap.php --configuration X:\ampp\htdocs\zf2\module\Application\test\phpunit.xml.dist X:\ampp\htdocs\zf2
>   Testing started at 11:01 AM ...
>
> Fatal error: Class 'ZendTest\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable\CredentialTreatmentAdapterTest' not found in X:\ampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\ZF2\tests\ZendTest\Authentication\Adapter\DbTableTest.php on line 23
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0982     206912   1. {main}() C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:0
>       0.1485     575992   2. IDE_Base_PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main(???) C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:498
>       0.1486     582288   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(???, ???) C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:260
>       1.3789    3182400   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest(???, ???, ???) X:\ampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:150
>      35.4471    3492552   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles(???) X:\ampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:96
>      39.6498    4293048   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile(???, ???) X:\ampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:416
>      39.6512    4293248   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad(???) X:\ampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:355
>      39.6534    4293376   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load(???) X:\ampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Fileloader.php:76
>      39.6552    4296576   9. include_once('X:\ampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\ZF2\tests\ZendTest\Authentication\Adapter\DbTableTest.php') X:\ampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Util\Fileloader.php:92
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around a bit .. I found out that the missing file and the folder which contains it are Tests which are meant for the framework and not for your specific skeleton application and hence I deleted that tests folder completely. After which my tests ran.

I'd like someone to validate my analysis.